# Intel Compute Stick as a test server

Tags: automated-builds

Does anyone use [Intel Compute Stick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Compute_Stick) to run auto dev. tests? Could it be used like that? Configuration would be as simple as possible:

- .NET, the latest;
- [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) or similar;
- Selenium WebDriver for IE or other browsers;
- possibly Visual Studio 2013/2015;
- Sql Server Express;
- IIS Express or IIS7;
- and various nuget packages.

Probably 32GB should be enough for all this.

Comment: Why do you think it cannot be used? It's a computer.

Comment: Tests can run like that but if it will be useful? What's their performance?

Comment: I've purchased few, and I'll find out, as I need to run some compute tests as well.